# How to find an identifier in Eclipse that's only preceded by white space?

Tags: regex, eclipse

Using Eclipse I want to find an identifier where it is not preceded by anything but white spaces:

```
ident                // match
  ident              // match
    ident            // match
//  ident            // no match
  //ident            // no match
blah_ident           // no match
```

That I have managed (`^[\s]*ident`). However, this also captures the preceding white space, which is not what I want. (Especially since it also captures preceding empty line.)

**In Eclipse, how do find an identifier that's preceded by white space without also capturing the white space?**

Comment: Are you trying to perform a replacement?

Comment: @arshajii: Eventually, I might. Right now it's mainly intellectual curiosity.

Comment: If I understand you correct, use a lookahead to consume and capture. [^(?=(ident)|\s+(ident))](http://regex101.com/r/pQ8eY9)

Comment: @hwnd: This doesn't find anything in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way consists to use a capturing group and a reference `$1` in the replacement string to let spaces before `ident` as it:

```
search:    ^(\h*)ident 
replace:   $1WhatYouWant
```

An other way uses the lookbehind feature (that seems to support variable length subpatterns in Luna):

```
search:   (?<=^\h*)ident
replace:  WhatYouWant
```

Comment: This will not capture empty lines in front of `ident`, but it does capture other whitespace.

Comment: @sbi: If you want to capture empty lines in front replace `\h` with `\s`. I used `\h` to avoid this.

Comment: Your second idea yells `Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 6` at me. (That goes away when I use `\s`, but that takes forever and seems to miss occurrences.) And I do _not_ want to capture leading whitespace, neither newlines nor anything else.

Comment: @sbi: the two patterns work well in Luna. And these two solutions are the only ways to match `ident` and to ensure that it is not commented. The first pattern is the more "portable", if your eclipse version is too old, replace `\h` with `[^\S\r\n]`.

Comment: Ok, the search is finished. Searching for `(?<=^\s*)ident` took forever (almost 10mins, whereas other patterns finish in <5secs), but it did find all occurrences and it captured only `ident`, so it is what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: @sbi: As I have said previously, `\h` works well, your eclipse version is too old. You need to upgrade if you want to have this character class, or use the previous replacement character class I suggest you in my precedent comment. Now, the first way that uses a capturing group, is probably the fastest.

Comment: Nice that you showed the two options, it's funny how many ways there can be of doing replacements... If he has `\K` we'd have a third option :) +1

Comment: @zx81: Thanks, but unfortunately, the last version available today (Eclipse Luna) does not have yet this useful feature. (However it has variable length lookbehind, that is slow but works).

Comment: And that's even better of course... I always think of `\K` as a hack for engines that don't have infinite lookbehind but care about their users enough to give something in that direction... Can't think of something `\K` can do that infinite lookbehind cannot do. Mentioned it just for fun, to round up the different ways, I know you're fully (expertly) aware of it. :)

Comment: @zx81: I do not have infinite lookbehind. I hacked around this by doing `(\s){0,1000}` instead. For me, since I only search reasonably formatted human-written source code, this is good enough.